# Leftalign, align and have only one number

Tags: equations, numbering

I have an equation that I want to leftalign. Also I needed to split this equation due to its length and since we are talking only about one equation, I want to give this equation only one number, not one in each row.

I created this minimal example

```
 \begin{flalign*}
    \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &\\
      &= \Lambda &\\
      &= \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 &
  \end{flalign*}
```

This does the first two things leftalign and align, but here each row gets a number, how can I change this?

Comment: put `\nonumber` or (`\notag`) before `\\ ` where you don't want number.

Comment: do you want *all* your display math flush left?  if so, there is another way, with better results for a display with an even number of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\nonumber` (or `\notag`) or `aligned` as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% for demo

\begin{document}
   \begin{flalign}
    \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &\notag\\
      &= \Lambda &\\
      &= \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 & \notag
  \end{flalign}
   \begin{flalign}
    &\!\begin{aligned}
    \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &\\
      &= \Lambda &\\
      &= \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 &
    \end{aligned}&
  \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]